# Xcode 9 Hide storyboard status bar

Tags: xcode, storyboard, statusbar

I can hide the status bar in my application easily enough, but I can't seem to get rid of it in the storyboard. It doesn't really affect anything - it's just a little annoying. The simulated metrics setting I used to use is gone.  Is there a new way to hide the status bar in storyboards?